# Access vars from factory in its run() method

Tags: angularjs, factory

How can I access vars from a factory inside it's run method?

```
(function()
{
    'use strict';

    angular.module('services',[])
    .factory('Hello',function()
    {
        var data;
    })
    .run(function()
    {
        //Get access to data var here
    });
}());
```

This is probably not possible and I will have to move `var data;` to outside the factory function, right? (e.g. http://plnkr.co/edit/1sHvg0oy0Y6o20SKrTnb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject the factory into the module's `.run` function:

```
myApp.factory('Hello', function () {
    var data;
    return {
        getData: function () {
            return data;
        },
        setData: function (val) {
            data = val;
        }
    };    
});
myApp.run(function (Hello) {
    Hello.setData(2);
});
```

Here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xph8n/

Or here's a solution that seems closer to your needs.  It uses the more generic provider which returns a `getData()` function while keeping a private `setData()`.  Then the private function can be called using `.config` with the associated provider being passed in:

```
myApp.provider('Hello', function () {

    this.data = 0;
    this.$get = function () {
        var data = this.data;
        return {
            getData: function () {
                return data;
            }
        }
    };  
    this.setData = function (data) {
        this.data = data;
    };
});

myApp.config(function (HelloProvider) {
    HelloProvider.setData(1);
});
```

The fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/xph8n/3/

Comment: Good point. However I wanted to access a method, `setData()` that I don't want to have available outside. Would this approach be wrong? http://plnkr.co/edit/1sHvg0oy0Y6o20SKrTnb Thanks.

Comment: Interesting idea wrapping it in a closure.  It feels risky to me to block angular's data access like that.  Another route you could go is to make 2 services, one public with limited access and then inject into it a private one that has the set method.  You'd use private for run but use the public everywhere else.  It wouldn't force privacy though, it'd be more of a policy approach (akin to how angular uses $$- they say it's private, don't use it.  But there's nothing actually stopping you other than the policy).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, sorry. Why would that be blocking Angular's access to data?

Comment: Your plunker is creating a closure around the data.  Maybe that's just for demo purposes though?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to put `data` into the global javascript namespace.  Which moving out of a function/closure would do...

Comment: Nope, I actually want `data` to only be available in the scope of that IIFE.

Comment: Makes sense- an IIFE being a form of closure.  So then I go back to worrying about hiding everything inside the IIFE from Angular (that you don't return to the outside world).  It is an interesting idea- and maybe it'd work but I worry...  Really I think you're up against javascript's limited data hiding facilities.  If we were talking objective-C or C++ for instance, then clearly you'd have lots of nice options.  I know I struggle with that aspect of javascript sometimes.

Comment: I am exposing parts of `data` via getters and allowing changes via setters. Basically, angular shouldn't know about data, only what the factory returns. Would that be wrong in your opinion?

Comment: I found a few examples doing exactly what you're doing with an IIFE so perhaps it's not so scary after all.  But I also have another idea for you to check out, I added it the answer above.

Comment: +1 for clear example how to use `providers` inside `.config` and inside `controller`s.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but your structure is incorrect

```
(function()
{
    'use strict';

    angular.module('services',[])
    .factory('Hello',function()
    {
        var data;
        return data;
    })
    .run(function(Hello)
    {
        //Hello points to the service variable.
    });
}());
```

Comment: `Hello` will be `data` because you're returning `data` instead of an object containing it.

Comment: Hm, thanks. However, I don't want data to be available to controllers for example. The factory will return a public interface which was removed from the code above. I take I will have to declare `var data;` in the IIFE but before the factory definition?

Comment: Yes you can do it that way but then you are not using AnuglarJS DI. And factories are there to share data, it cannot be restricted.

Comment: What do you mean? If I do something like `var data; (...).factory('Hello',function(){return data;}).run(function(){data=1;});` it won't work the same?

Comment: It would work, but as you have shown for `Hello` service it is exposing the `data` so anyone can see it.

Comment: I know, it was an example, it's awful to write inline code. Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/1sHvg0oy0Y6o20SKrTnb

Comment: Will the code in the plunkr snippet not work with the DI in Angular? I don't see why not.